# Matplotlib: set superscript font size

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Matplotlib, how can I set the font size of a superscript (in addition to controlling the font size of the base)?
For example, creating a graph with Matplotlib with axes in scientific notation: it is easy to set the font size of the tick labels, but how can I specify the font size of their exponents?
I want to differentially have a control on the base AND on the exponent (i.e., playing on the font size of the tick labels to obtain an exponent of desired size is not a good option - can we modify the ratio of the font sizes of the base and exponent?).
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have exponents, there are essentially two possibilities you have obtained the text:

1. By using an external TeX installation (in which case you have `rcParams['text.usetex'] == True`).
2. By using the `mathtext` Tex clone built into `matplotlib`

If you are using an external TeX installation, then it is up to TeX (my guess is something like `\DeclareMathSizes{10}{18}{12}{8}`, but I have not tried that).

If you are using the "standard" method, then the font size ratios are hard-coded into `matplotlib`. So, there is no way to change them; a superscript is 70 % of the base font as per Donald Knuth's original TeX specification.

---

And after having that "no way" said, I'll show a way. But it is not a beautiful path...

As `matplotlib` is mostly written in Python, you may change a lot of things. The parameters you want are in the file `.../matplotlib/mathtext.py`. That `...` depends on your Python distribution and operating system. (For example, mine is `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py`)

In that file there should be around line 1200 something like:

```
# How much text shrinks when going to the next-smallest level.  GROW_FACTOR
# must be the inverse of SHRINK_FACTOR.
SHRINK_FACTOR   = 0.7
GROW_FACTOR     = 1.0 / SHRINK_FACTOR
# The number of different sizes of chars to use, beyond which they will not
# get any smaller
NUM_SIZE_LEVELS = 6
# Percentage of x-height of additional horiz. space after sub/superscripts
SCRIPT_SPACE    = 0.2
# Percentage of x-height that sub/superscripts drop below the baseline
SUBDROP         = 0.3
# Percentage of x-height that superscripts drop below the baseline
SUP1            = 0.5
# Percentage of x-height that subscripts drop below the baseline
SUB1            = 0.0
# Percentage of x-height that superscripts are offset relative to the subscript
DELTA           = 0.18
```

You may change these to make the text spacing different. For example, let us make a simple test graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,5, 1000)
y = np.sin(x**2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x_1$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$sin(x_1^2)$')
ax.text(.5, -.5, r'$\rm{this\ is}_\mathrm{subscript}$', fontsize=24)
ax.text(.5, -.7, r'$\rm{this\ is}^\mathrm{superscript}$', fontsize=24)
ax.text(.5, -.9, r'$\frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{3}}$', fontsize=24)
```

This gives:

[image]

Then we do some magic:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.mathtext.SHRINK_FACTOR = 0.5
matplotlib.mathtext.GROW_FACTOR = 1 / 0.5
```

And run the same drawing code again:

[image]

As you can see, the super/subscript size changed. But unfortunately it has side effects, if you have a look at the fraction.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DrV, it does the job - this is what I was looking for! [Sorry I cannot vote up]

Comment: For me (mpl version 2.1.2), I had to set 

    mpl.mathtext.FontConstantsBase.sup1 = 0.9

to get any effect. Changing just mpl.mathtext.sup1 didn't do anything. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837171/matplotlib-2-0-subscript-outside-of-baseline-when-super-and-subscript-are-both-u

Comment: For mpl version 3.4.3, the parameters save file changed to _mathtext.py, so I used:
matplotlib._mathtext.SHRINK_FACTOR = 0.8
matplotlib._mathtext.GROW_FACTOR = 1 / 0.8
It works, thanks a lot!